# How can I protect my dog from mosquitos?

Tags: dogs, mosquitoes

I am concerned about these things:

1. The health impact to my dog.
2. My dog's sleep and my sleep:  my dog snaps at the mosquitos all night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opted for [Insect Shield Repellent Bandana](http://www.insectshieldforpets.com/).  I'd rate it a 3 out of 5 for effectiveness, 5 out of 5 for value.

Comment: http://www.insectshieldforpets.com/

Answer (score 9):

Many of the medicines which work for ticks also work well against mosquitoes.  Since you are taking your dog outdoors and will thus need flea and tick protection anyways, consider that as an option

Example:  [https://www.amazon.com/Advantix-Large-Dogs-55-Pound-6-Month](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QRJJ0K)

There are many brands, no preference shown other than being the easiest to find a link for.

Answer (score 1):

If your dog(s) ever wear any clothing then permethrin may be a good choice.

from the website: https://www.mosquito.org/page/repellents
"Permethrin-containing products (Permanone) are recommended for use only on clothing, shoes, bednets and camping gear—never on skin. Permethrin does kill mosquitoes and ticks and is highly effective. Permethrin-treated clothing repels and kills ticks, mosquitoes and other arthropods.  It remains effective even after repeated laundering. Permethrin-treated clothing should be safe when label directions are followed."

When I am out camping (or hiking), my dogs wear a vest that has been treated with Permethrin. In addition to working well, it is also very inexpensive.

Comment: Probably best to considered whether your dog has a habit to chew on anything it can get its mouth on.

Answer (score 0):

If your dog sleeps in a bench, you can sew mosquito netting around the outside of the bench and on its door, with an extra strip to cover the opening.

For dogs who get more space to sleep you may make a cage with netting or you can even keep a part or your house mosquito free with netting. Windows, doors, ventilation shafts and any other openings need to be well covered with netting. And you need to be vigilant in keeping the doors and windows closed and/or covered by netting.

Depending on how often your dog is outside and how much he is bothered by mosquitos there you may still want to use a chemical to dispel the insects.